# React native delete multiple items from state array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-image

I have a directory which stores images taken using the camera. For saving images I am using [RNFS](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs). I am using [react-native-photo-browser](https://github.com/halilb/react-native-photo-browser).

The gallery itself doesn't have any options to delete the items from the gallery. So I am working to achieve it

```
export default class GridGallery extends React.Component{

    static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Image Gallery',
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          filesList : [],
          mediaSelected: [],
          base64URI: null,
          galleryList: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        FileList.list((files) => {

            if(files != null) {

                this.fileUrl = files[0].path;

                files = files.sort((a, b) => {

                    if (a.ctime < b.ctime)
                        return 1;
                    if (a.ctime > b.ctime)
                        return -1;
                    return 0;
                });

                this.setState({
                    filesList: files
                });
            }
            console.warn(this.state.filesList);
            this.getFiles();
        });
      }

    getFiles(){
      //console.warn(this.state.filesList);

      const ArrFiles = this.state.filesList.map((file) =>
        ({ caption : file.name, photo : file.path })
      );
      //console.warn(ArrFiles);

      this.setState({ galleryList : ArrFiles });
    }

    onActionButton = (media, index) => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
          ActionSheetIOS.showShareActionSheetWithOptions(
            {
              url: media.photo,
              message: media.caption,
            },
            () => {},
            () => {},
          );
        } else {
          alert(`handle sharing on android for ${media.photo}, index: ${index}`);
        }
      };

      handleSelection = async (media, index, isSelected) => {
        if (isSelected == true) {
            this.state.mediaSelected.push(media.photo);
        } else {
         this.state.mediaSelected.splice(this.state.mediaSelected.indexOf(media.photo), 1);
        }
         console.warn(this.state.mediaSelected);
      }

      deleteImageFile = () => {

        const dirPicutures = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;
        //delete mulitple files
        console.warn(this.state.mediaSelected);
        this.state.mediaSelected.map((file) =>
        // filepath = `${dirPicutures}/${file}`
          RNFS.exists(`${file}`)
          .then( (result) => {
              console.warn("file exists: ", result);

              if(result){
                return RNFS.unlink(`${file}`)
                  .then(() => {
                    console.warn('FILE DELETED');
                    let tempgalleryList = this.state.galleryList.filter(item => item.photo !== file);
                    this.setState({ galleryList : tempgalleryList })
                  })
                  // `unlink` will throw an error, if the item to unlink does not exist
                  .catch((err) => {
                    console.warn(err.message);
                  });
              }

            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.warn(err.message);
            })
        )

     }

     renderDelete(){
       const { galleryList } = this.state;
       if(galleryList.length>0){
         return(
           <View style={styles.topRightContainer}>
           <TouchableOpacity style={{alignItems: 'center',right: 10}} onPress={this.deleteImageFile}>
             <Image
               style={{width: 24, height: 24}}
               source={require('../assets/images/ic_delete.png')}
             />
             </TouchableOpacity>
           </View>
         )
       }
     }

     goBack() {
       const { navigation } = this.props;
       navigation.pop;
     }

    render() {
      const { galleryList } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <PhotoBrowser
                    mediaList={galleryList}
                    enableGrid={true}
                    displayNavArrows={true}
                    displaySelectionButtons={true}
                    displayActionButton={true}
                    onActionButton={this.onActionButton}
                    displayTopBar = {true}
                    onSelectionChanged={this.handleSelection}
                    startOnGrid={true}
                    initialIndex={0}
                />
                </View>
                {this.renderDelete()}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**An example list of images:**

```
[
    {
     photo:'4072710001_f36316ddc7_b.jpg',
      caption: 'Grotto of the Madonna',
      },
      {
        photo: /media/broadchurch_thumbnail.png,
        caption: 'Broadchurch Scene',
      },
      {
        photo:
          '4052876281_6e068ac860_b.jpg',
          caption: 'Beautiful Eyes',
      },
  ]
```

My aim is whenever the item from state `galleryList` is removed I need to refresh the component, so the deleted image will be removed from the gallery. So When I try to use filter the `galleryList` it deleting other images instead of other images:

```
let tempgalleryList = this.state.galleryList.filter(item => item.photo !== file);
                    this.setState({ galleryList : tempgalleryList })
```

[MCVE](https://github.com/jothikannan/gallery-browser) -> This is a minified version of my code, you can see the images are deleting randomly

Comment: So what is actually happening?

Comment: It deleting the images from the directory but from UI it deleting random images.

Comment: Is `this.state.mediaSelected.map` supposed to really be `this.state.mediaSelected.forEach`?

Comment: @DrewReese nope, forEach also working like same way

Comment: Well, `map` returns a new array with the same number of elements (which your code doesn't capture), and `forEach` calls a function for each element.  How you're using it is, ofc, doing the same thing and working the same way since you're never returning a new value to map to.  Was just pointing out that your code should probably be using the `forEach` instead.

Comment: Probably you have a component that is responsable for list the items, try to add the key attribute to this element. Something like that:

this.state.galleryList.map(item => <ItemComponent key={item.photo} ...>)

I guess this logic is on PhotoBrowser component, make sure you put a key that is unique.

hope it helps

Comment: @LeonardoLobato there is key attribute already present in the ListView

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Problem

```
let tempgalleryList = this.state.galleryList.filter(item => item.photo !== file);
this.setState({ galleryList : tempgalleryList })
```

Since `setState` is async, `this.state.galleryList` will not be updated in each iteration of your `map` function, so the final updated state will only have one item filtered out instead of all selected items.

#### Solution

You can use the [callback version of `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) which uses the updated state instead:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ 
  galleryList : prevState.galleryList.filter(item => item.photo !== file), 
}));
```

#### Alternative solution

Instead of calling `setState` in every iteration, you can call it outside of your `map` function instead (though `setState` updates will be batched anyway so no significant performance improvement):

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ 
  galleryList : prevState.galleryList.filter(item => !prevState.mediaSelected.includes(item.photo)), 
}));
```

#### Other problems with your code

```
  this.state.mediaSelected.push(media.photo); 
} else {
  this.state.mediaSelected.splice(this.state.mediaSelected.indexOf(media.photo), 1);
```

You are directly mutating your state here. Do this instead:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ 
  mediaSelected: prevState.mediaSelected.concat(media.photo) 
})); 

this.setState(prevState => ({ 
  mediaSelected: prevState.mediaSelected.filter(e => e != media.photo) 
}));
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185830/discussion-on-answer-by-riwu-react-native-delete-multiple-items-from-state-array).